# Change pandas default string format for Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

**TL;DR:**

Is there a way to change the *default* string representation of [pandas' `Timestamp`s](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)?

**Long version:**

For example, say I was not interested in the seconds of the timestamps and I have a large number of `print` statements. By default, pandas will print the timestamps including seconds:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01T12')

print(f"Timestamp: {ts}")
# Timestamp: 2017-01-01 12:00:00
```

I can change this by passing a format string:

```
print(f"Timestamp: {ts.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}")
# Timestamp: 2017-01-01 12:00
```

However, I would need to add the `strftime` call and format string explicitly for every timestamp in every `print`. Is there a way to change the default format that is used to represent timestamps (other than wrapping them in a function to do the string conversion myself)?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, I think the best way for you to be to create a function to do it and in each time call the function

Comment: As far as I know, this is only possible for float values through the float_format option

Comment: The output is hardcoded in `__str__` (or `__repr__`), there is no possibility to configure it. But of course, you can always use monkey patching to change that behavior

Comment: If you have checked that it is indeed hardcoded and there is no hidden option, this is likely the only way to do it and you may want to make your comment an answer.